# What is the name for the binary sequence 0110100110010110?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary

This is a special sequence formed by:
0
0 + 1(its opposite)
01 + 10(its opposite)
0110 + 1001(its opposite)
01101001 + 10010110(its opposite)

What is it called?

Comment: Palindrom or however it's spelled?

Answer (score 7):

It's called **Thue–Morse sequence**

[Here's a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)